# C++ exe to dll to use as a component (CLR)

Tags: c#, c++, dll, components, exe

I have a Program.exe which is written with c++. And a c++ file that shows c++ exe source codes only.

So first of all I tried to use Cmake program to change and debug c++ exe. After this I must convert it a .dll file such as this .dll file can be used as a component in c# (CLR).

How could I do this?

Comment: Ever heard of "Platform Invoke"? You can do a little bit research. You don't really to convert C++ to C#.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, that program has some functions you want to use in C#? In such case, convert the project from exe to (native) DLL and then use P/Invoke:

How to make DLL:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636(v=vs.80).aspx

Platform invoke from DLL:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx